# Facebook SDK: Create Project from existing source is empty

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I have tried to use this [tutorial](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/) and when I clicked finished, I have noticed that the src was empty, screenshot below: The facebook project in my folder is complete, so my question do I need to manually copy all the files to the folder? And why was this empty?

[image]

Edited:
I'm using Eclipse Indigo and Android ADT Version 18.

Comment: How are you importing the facebook project into eclipse ?

Comment: Using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#ref

Comment: It has to import the src files into the folder as well. Instead of copying the files manually into /src folder do following: Right click on empty /src folder > Import > General > File System > Select /src directory of facebook project > Mark the checkbox with src option > Finish

Comment: Thanks a lot! Shall I include AndroidManifest.xml and some other files?

Comment: Please see the answer that will surely resolve every thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have created your project with empty folders do the following:

1) Right Click on the project

2) Click Import

3) General > File System

4) Select the "facebook" folder that is inside the downloaded package

5) Check mark the facebook option

6) Finish

This will import all the files that are part of the facebook project.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from [this tutorial](http://ericosgood.com/prog/facebook-android-sdk-tutorial/#comments) as this method is somewhat chaotic, there's some other way by going to Right-clicking your project -> Build Path -> Link Source -> Browse to the "facebook" directory, and that's it, hope it gave you all some idea.